# Convergence of semi-alternating harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble showing whether or not the following series converges:
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}...$$
I've tried using several methods, such as creating two leibniz series from the terms, or using comparison tests, but failed to prove anything.  Does this series converge and why? Thank you.

Comment: $$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9})+...$$
 is convergent and the remaining part is divergent . Hence the series is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Ignore all but the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, ... terms, with the idea that the remainder of the terms (i.e. the ones being ignored) have a positive sum.  Then, compare the terms not being ignored to (1/3) of the harmonic series, which is known to be divergent.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed the fact that this sum is (of the 2 sums) is divergent

Answer (score 1):

The isolating of the first, fourth etc terms is the first thing I thought of, as in another proposed answer.

Another way is to group the terms other than the first in threes and study $$\frac 1{3n-1}-\frac 1{3n}+\frac 1{3n+1}$$ which (from the curvature of the reciprocal function I expect to be greater than $\dfrac 1{3n}$ which will do for comparison - indeed even if close to $3n$ a comparison is likely to be possible).